# Long async calculation with callback in Python Flask Webservice

Tags: python, flask, python-asyncio

I would like to implement a webservice in python that would behave as follows:

```
request to service: mysvc.com/doSomethingLong?callbackurl=http://callbackurl
response (immediate): 200 OK
```

(long time passes, python calculation completed)

```
service makes an http request to the received callback url: http://callbackurl
```

What would be the best approach to do this?

Most examples I see for async calculations, do not return the immediate "200 OK", but rather await for the response, while yielding control to allow other code to work in parallel.

Comment: use `celery` tasks

Comment: Thanks @RomanPerekhrest. Would you still suggest it, if the "long calculations" were 20 seconds? I was hoping to avoid a full fledges task-queue service. Is there any alternative?

Comment: also you may consider using a subprocess that will keep running after the main script ended

Comment: This is a web service (flask app), what do you mean "the main script ended"?. What are the drawbacks of simply starting a thread? (e.g.: threading.Thread(target=long_process, args=(params, callback_url))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution for running asynchronous tasks in a Flask app that enables returning an immediate response is [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor).

> *class* concurrent.futures.**ThreadPoolExecutor**(*max_workers=None, thread_name_prefix='', initializer=None, initargs=()*)
>
> An [Executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor) subclass that uses a pool of at most *max_workers* threads to execute calls asynchronously.
>
> *initializer* is an optional callable that is called at the start of each worker thread; *initargs* is a tuple of arguments passed to the initializer. Should *initializer* raise an exception, all currently pending jobs will raise a [BrokenThreadPool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.thread.BrokenThreadPool), as well as any attempt to submit more jobs to the pool.
>
> *Changed in version 3.5*: If *max_workers* is `None` or not given, it will default to the number of processors on the machine, multiplied by `5`, assuming that ThreadPoolExecutor is often used to overlap I/O instead of CPU work and the number of workers should be higher than the number of workers for [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor).
>
> *New in version 3.6*: The *thread_name_prefix* argument was added to allow users to control the [threading.Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) names for worker threads created by the pool for easier debugging.
>
> *Changed in version 3.7*: Added the *initializer* and *initargs* arguments.

## Flask Example

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from flask import Blueprint, request
from werkzeug.wrappers import BaseResponse as Response

client_session = Blueprint('client_session', __name__)


@client_session.route('/session-login', methods=['POST', 'PUT'])
def session_login():

    ...

    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(5)
    executor.submit(my_long_running_task, my_task_param=42)

    # Return response immediately.
    return Response(
        response='{"status_text": "OK"}',
        status=200,
        mimetype='application/json; charset=UTF-8')
```

For pre-configured design patterns for working with `ThreadPoolExecutor` in Flask, see [**Flask-Executor**](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Executor/).

---

## [Example from Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example)

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of ThreadPoolExecutor() each time the route is accessed? I would have thought you should create a single instance of ThreadPoolExecutor() when Flask starts and then call submit() on that instance when processing the route, no?

Comment: @IanAsh Yes, an instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor` could be cached and reused. I updated the answer with a reference to the package `Flask-Executor`, which provides design patterns for working with `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: After considering alternatives, I've initially implemented a basic thread based solution using: `x = threading.Thread(target, args)`, `x.start()`. This solution seems like a much safer way to manage resources. Accepted. Thanks.